# Bootstrap Date picker at unusual position

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using a checkbox for toggling between datepicker and monthpicker. Its working fine if I open them one at a time (i.e close one before toggling). But if I toggle the checkbox while the datepicker/monthpicker is still open, then the new popup is opening at a wrong position.

I don't know what i am doing wrong. I have not worked on css before.

**for datepicker**

[image]

**and this is where it's going for a picnic**

[image]

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="span3 custom-style-datepicker" ng-if="permission" >
   <label class="control-label" translate="date"></label>
   <div class="span4" ng-show="reconModel.isEnabled">
      <input type="text" class="form-control recon-date" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="vm.reconModel.date" is-open="isFromOpen" show-weeks="false" ng-click="isFromOpen=!isToOpen" min-mode="'month'" datepicker-mode="'month'" />
   </div>
   <div id="here" class="span4" ng-show="!reconModel.isEnabled">
      <input type="text" class="form-control recon-date" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="vm.reconModel.date" is-open="isFromOpen" ng-click="isFromOpen=!isToOpen" show-weeks="false"  />
   </div>
   <div class="switchable-dp " style="padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px">
      <input type="checkbox" name="isEnabled" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" switch-active="{{permission}}" switch-on-text="Month Picker" switch-off-text="Date Picker" switch-off-color="success" switch-label="" switch-radio-off="{{permission}}" ng-init="reconModel.isEnabled=true" ng-model="reconModel.isEnabled" switch-size="mini" bs-switch  data-label-width="0">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML is not sufficient to solve your problem. If possible do create [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: It's seems that you are using angularjs. Please create [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/) with your problem.